# If $X$ is a non empty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y = [1,2]$ then $X+Y$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

If $X$ is a non empty closed subset of  $\mathbb{R}$ and  $Y = [1,2]$ then $X+Y$ is closed?

How to show this?

I know that sum of two closed set may not be closed. But how to prove this? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \in X,y_n \in [1,2]$ and $x_n +y_n \to z$. Since $[1,2]$ is compact there is  a subsequence $y_{n_{k}}$ which converges to some point $y$ in $[1,2]$. But $x_{n_{k}}+y_{n_{k}} \to z$ so $x_{n_{k}} \to z-y$. Since $X$ is closed, $z-y \in X$. It follows that $z= \lim (x_{n_{k}}+y_{n_{k}}) =(z-y)+y \in X+Y$.

Comment: Can I use this technic if $X$ and $Y$ were subsets of any NLS and one is compact and another is closed?@Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @cmi Yes, the same argument works for the sum of  a closed set and a compact set in any NLS.

Comment: In any topological group if you use nets instead of sequences. @cmi

Comment: Yes, you are right again.

Answer (score 1):

And an answer to the second part of your question.
Let $X=\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$, $Y=\{y:y=-n+\frac1n, n=2,3,4,\ldots\}$. They are closed, but in their sum there is a set $\{\frac1n:n=2,3,4, \ldots\}$ but not $0$.

Comment: I knew that. ……….